# What config value should I set to make the HZ value (jiffies) physically correct?

Tags: build, linux-kernel, kernel, clock, arm64

When build linux kernel Image, we set the value `HZ`. linux kernel has the default `HZ` value. It is a software clock frequency the kernel operates at and `1/HZ (=jiffies)` is the unit of scheduler interval. Of course this `HZ` should be coming from a real hardware timer generating timer interrupt. So my question is : we can set `HZ` when building kernel image, but what CONFIG value should I change (especially for arm64 case) to apply the real clock frequency this timer is running at? I believe there should be a CONFIG value because some FPGA boards can be running at lower clock frequency and it is dependent on hardware design. If this config value is not correct, the 250MHz will not be really 250MHz. What CONFIG value should I change? Or, is the timer clock frequency of all the processors fixed like standard? (like RTC clock is 32.768MHz?)

Comment: The kernel configuration menus only let you pick 100, 250, 300 or 1000, with 250 Hz being the default.

Comment: Also, the HZ configuration is downstream from the clock frequency configuration. The clock source frequencies are usually defined in places such as the device tree or ACPI tables.